# Trouble receiving Javascript variable when sent to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

### Problem: Trouble receiving what is being sent to my PHP document.

### Javascript:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var message;
    var myRegExp = validation stuff
    var urlToValidate = document.getElementById("url").value;
    if (!myRegExp.test(urlToValidate)){
        }else{
    var code = (urlToValidate).slice(-22)
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event){
    if (this.readyState == 4){
        if (this.status ==200){
            console.log (this.status);
        }else{
            console.log('Server replied with HTTP status ' + this.status);
        }
    }
});

request.open('POST', 'php/submit.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

request.send("code=" + code);
}   
});
```

### Then I'm using this code on my php/submit.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['code'])) { 
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    echo $code; 
};
```

I feel like I'm not using the right tag names for PHP because I'm new to all of this. I'll note that I'm using form id but getting the value from an input.

Ramblings
I'm trying to send a user input that has been validated and sliced to mySQL database.

I achieved the string I wanted with javascript and passed it to a variable.

I'm trying to send it to a separate php file in another folder with a request.send(the_javaS_variable).

Now in the console I can see the variable holds the correct text value and I see it sending with state 4 and 200.

But it never shows up on the submit.php page.

Comment: You cannot use console.log in php, that is a javascript thing.

Comment: try using 'die(var_dump($_POST));' in your php to see if you have any values being sent over

Comment: Why are you using JQuery and not using the JQuery AJAX functions.

Comment: @Scott he is already doing an `echo $code;` what use woudl dieing do.

Comment: @Hobbes I've been at this for so long that I was trying anything to get it to appear, because I felt like I was going crazy, I think I did go crazy.  Guess I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Try removing this line `request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` as plain text header will stop PHP from looking for posted data.

Comment: read this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @RiggsFolly ha, I didn't actually see that as I was staring at the console.log.

Comment: @developerwjk All I need is the string, to put in to a database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Alright, removed that line, still no go.

I'll check out your link. Thanks.

Comment: @Scott
I get " array(0) { } "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and remove the `console.log()`

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(event){
    var myRegExp = validation stuff
    var urlToValidate = document.getElementById("url").value;
    if (!myRegExp.test(urlToValidate)){
        // failed
    }else{

        var code = 'code='+(urlToValidate).slice(-22);

        $.post('php/submit.php', code, function() {
            //   success stuff
        });

    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I just wanted to say that I ended up scrapping everything I had and learned a bit about AJAX. I used this code when I rewrote everything and it works, thanks.